# how to modify default title in a Scroll Activity

Tags: android

How can I modify the default title given when you create a Scroll Activity. I was only able to change the title name which I it called "Food Name" in the image. How can I add margin or padding to it and add more titles that have the same properties as you scroll down the "Food Name" gets smaller and smaller.

[activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tytau.png)

activity_scrolling.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="545dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/food1"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow"
            android:id="@id/back_Arrow"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling">

</include>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my activity_scrolling.xml but its isnt located here.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it at Manifest 
android:label="@string/app_name"

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late for you, but may be helpful to others.
Here is how you can modify default title in a Scroll **Activity**

```
private void actionBarSupport() {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Set Title");
    }
}
```

In fragment you can get action bar support like this:

```
private void actionBarSupport() {
   if (((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null) {

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
}
```

}